# All custom page tabs showing blank canvas

Tags: facebook, tabs

Randomly late last week, all of my custom page tabs have started showing blank canvas. As an example, the below link just shows a blank canvas when before Friday 11/2 it was a working graphic with a link to an external page.

I submitted a support ticket with Facebook but have not heard back other than them marking the priority as LOW. Has anybody else recently experienced this issue? And has there been any word of a workaround?

Some of my tabs have been visible for months only to just show a blank canvas. I need to know if something has been changed with Facebook where I need to adjust the code? Or does this sound like its a Facebook issue if my pages were previously working?

Thanks for any assistance!

Example tab here: http://www.facebook.com/DallasCowboys/app_161433827333379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.shopcowboys.com/pagefiles/dcfacebook/boysof/index.asp get’s delivered with a HTTP response header

> x-frame-options:  SAMEORIGIN

– that tells the browser, that this page does not want to be displayed in any kind of frames (unless they are from the same domain) …

So disable this response header, if you want to use your pages inside Facebook. (If you don’t know how to, or why this even got enabled, ask your server admin.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am having our server admin take a look at this. Could you tell me how you were able to view the HTTP response header?

Comment: Well, first of all my browser (Opera) showed me a message saying that the page was prevented from being shown inside a frame, and then I just used http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https://www.shopcowboys.com/pagefiles/dcfacebook/boysof/index.asp to confirm that there was the header in question.